Required fields are missing: [ProfileId]: [ProfileId] error when tried to insert User record from a Test class

When tried to call a user insertion method i.e. Util.insertUserWithRole() in a Test class, by using System.runAs(existing user in org i.e. thisUser2), not getting any error.
When directly called user insertion method without writing System.runAs() in a Test class, not getting any error.
When tried to call a User insertion method, by using System.runAs(new user's instance i.e. thisUser1), getting 'Required fields are missing: [ProfileId]' exception while executing 'insert u;' statement. But if the User insertion method is a @future method then, no error.


@isTest
public class SampleSystemRunAsTest 
{
    @isTest
    static void test1()
    {
     User thisUser1 = new User(profileid = '00e5g000001pCh7AAE', userroleid = '00E5g000001QaLDEA0', username='Nmm@awcomputing.com', alias = 'NNNN', email='Nmm@awcomputing.com', emailencodingkey='UTF-8', lastname='SampleUser', languagelocalekey='en_US', localesidkey='en_US', timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles'); 
     //User thisUser2 = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()]; 
        System.runAs(thisUser1)
        {
            Test.startTest();        
            Util.insertUserWithRole('abc@awcomputing.com', 'mruizz', 'mruizzj@awcomputing.com', 'Ruizz');
            Test.stopTest();
        }
        User[] users = [SELECT Id from User where username='abc@awcomputing.com'];
        System.assertEquals(1, users.size());
    }
}

public class Util 
{
    public static void insertUserWithRole(String uname, String al, String em, String lname) 
    {
        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard Platform User'];
        UserRole r = [SELECT Id FROM UserRole WHERE Name='COO'];        
        User u = new User(alias = al, email=em,
            emailencodingkey='UTF-8', lastname=lname,
            languagelocalekey='en_US',
            localesidkey='en_US', profileid = p.Id, userroleid = r.Id,
            timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles',
            username=uname);
        insert u;
    }
} 

Want to know the difference between System.runAs(thisUser1) and System.runAs(thisUser2)?
Why am I getting error when used System.runAs(thisUser1)?
Why am I not getting error when user insertion method is a @future() and when  System.runAs(thisUser2) or when System.runAs() is removed?

since you are not inserting thisUser1 this may be working-as-designed. Try inserting thisUser1 before calling the Util method. It is not clear to me why you'd want to mock new users for test purpose using a running user other than the sysadmin user.

I got the answer. Since the Profile of thisUser1 has no access to create Users in the Org, it has thrown the error.
